# Force powerpoint to keep 100% scaling when dragging image onto slide

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a folder full of pdf images. I want to drag and drop individual images onto slides, potentially more that one per slide, and at arbitrary positions. All my images are pre-scaled so that they are exactly the desired size however some have extraneous white space or are larger than the slide dimensions. I am quite happy for bits of the image to extend beyond the viewable area.

For 'small' images their size is retained as expected. For 'large' images, I assume those that are bigger than the slide dimensions, PowerPoint is trying to be clever and scales them down. I don't want this behaviour? Is there a way to turn it off?